# Is there a magnetic line that is a Eucliden straight line?

Tags: magnetic-fields

In my (though few) experiences, magnetic lines are always curved (with respect to a Euclidean plane). I have never seen there is any magnetic line that is Euclidean straight.

If there is a magnetic line that is Euclidean straight, could you please give me an example? If not, then the existence of a Euclidean straight magnetic line contradicts what physics theories?

Comment: The field lines in the interior of a good solenoid are straight to quite a good approximation.

Comment: If you take a coil, the axis of symmetry is also a straight magnetic line, but all the others are curved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magnetic field lines are not straight because we have not found a mono magnetic pole yet.
 magnetic lines by a single pole can only be straight like electric field lines by a single positive charge or single negative charge.
But unlike electric charge ,magnetic charge always found is pairs(as far as we know there exist only magnetic dipole).
Thats why magnetic lines are not straight.

Comment: To expand on this, a magnetic field line can only begin or end on a magnetic monopole. Since magnetic monopoles don't exist (probably) all magnetic field lines must have no beginning or end i.e. they must be loops. And obviously a loop cannot be straight over its whole length, or it wouldn't be a loop.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Thanks very much. I think about something further to ask.