# How do electric field lines form only open loops?

Tags: electric-fields, dipole-moment

I understand that this is a consequence of the conservative nature of electric field, but then how does an electric dipole form closed loops?

Comment: the static electric lines do not form closed loop, the charges are singularities of the field lines

Comment: Yes, electrostatic field lines don't form closed loops because $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = 0$, meaning it is a curl-free vector field. This is a property of a conservative vector field, as it can be expressed as the gradient of some function. (In this case, the electric field being $E = -\nabla V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electric field lines of an electric dipole do not form closed loops .See here ,they begin at positive charges and end at negative charges.

[image]

But magnetic field lines form closed loops ,see the difference

[image]

Magnetic fields  form closed loops because there are no magnetic monopoles.

See this post for more information

[Is there a magnetic line that is a Eucliden straight line?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/is-there-a-magnetic-line-that-is-a-eucliden-straight-line)

But unlike magnetic monopoles electric monopoles exist in nature so electric field lines need not form closed loops.